# What does mean HIJACKED in server's log?

Tags: ruby, rack, puma, faye

I have Faye ruby server as rack app. I starts it with Puma. In Puma's output I see the next

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Apr/2015 15:32:37] "POST /faye HTTP/1.1" HIJACKED -1 0.0059
```

What does it mean and how can I avoid this? If I use Thin I have nothing like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that the [Rack Socket Hijacking Protocol](https://github.com/rack/rack/pull/481) is used. Not sure why it isn't used with Thin, or maybe, Thin just doesn't log it.

Comment: Thin normally uses a different method where new Rack would use socket hijacking. Thin is the original EventMachine-based app server, and does it that way.

Answer (score 1):

As Jorg says, this means it's using socket hijacking. That's not a bad thing, and not a problem. You should expect it when using Faye or any other [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) or long-polling method of pushing content to the browser.